# Doing a line break after X amount of results in a Foreach statement (PHP)

Tags: php, foreach, line-breaks

I've got a foreach statement that returns say 25 names

```
foreach($player as $item) {
  echo $player[$count++];
}
```

How do I make it so after X amount, lets say 10 names, it does a line break? The full code has avatars in i for example, so after the 10th avatar, the 11th one would start after a line break/

```
foreach($player as $item) {
  echo "<td align='center'><img src='" .  strtr ( $avatar[$count_avatar++], array ("avatar:" => "", ',' => '' )) . "'><br><font>" .  strtr ( $player[$count++], array ("name:" => "", ',' => '' )) . "</font></td><td class='character_spacer'></td>";
}
```

Comment: You can use `array_chunk()`  or a simple `$index > 0 && $index % 10 == 0`. You can get `$index` as `foreach($player as $index => $item)`

Comment: *"How do I make it so after X amount"* exactly once after X elements or **every** X elements?

Comment: Do you mean a line break, or as you are using tables a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$row_count = 0;
foreach($player as $item)
{
    $row_count++;
    if ($row_count == 10)
    {
        $row_count = 0;
        echo '<br />'; // It will not work within tr or td you have to add margins here according to your need.
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `foreach` and then use `$player[$count]` with it's own counter?

Comment: Side note: `<br/>` does not work between `<tr>`s and/or `<td>`s.

Comment: I just add the answer for reference. The questioner know its actual code and know how to add margins or space between tr or td.

Comment: Thanks John, Worked like a charm! For full reference to other people who stumble here, here's the same code with John Doe's fix `$count_chars = 0;
$row_count = 0;

foreach($player as $item)
{
 $row_count++;
 echo "<td align='center'><img src='" .  strtr ( $avatar[$count_avatar++], array ("avatar:" => "", ',' => '' )) . "'><br><font>" .  strtr ( $player[$count++], array ("name:" => "", ',' => '' )) . "</font></td><td class='character_spacer'></td>";
 
    if ($row_count == 11)
    { $row_count = 0;
 echo '</tr><tr>';
 }
    $count_chars++;
}`